# Forward Only Email Server

Tags: centos, sendmail

I have a custom domain (I'll use the real domains cause I'm desperate at this point :) ) www.grantorino.io, and I want to forward all email addresses sent to  yehiasalam@grantorino.io to yehia.asalam@gmail.com. I followed the logical steps but I can't seem to get it right. This is what I did so far:

1. Map the MX record to the grantorino server, [image: dig] a dig command shows that the mx have no problems, and that mail.grantorino.io maps correctly to my server.
2. Next step is allowing port 25 on the firewall settings, so it's now open to accept TCP connections from port 25[image: Webmin Firewall Settings]
3. Make Sendmail forward any mails from yehiasalam@grantorino.io to yehia.asalam@gmail.com. I started with allowing the virtuser feature, an excerpt from sendmail.mc

   FEATURE('virtusertable', 'hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
4. The virtusertable I added

   yehiasalam@grantorino.io     yehia.asalam@gmail.com

and compiled using `makemap hasg virtusertable.db < virtusertable`

5. Also in the access file I added

Connect:grantorino.io           RELAY

and compiled using `makemap hash access < access.db`

6. Finally in the sendmail.c I changed the DEAMON_OPTIONS line to

   DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet, Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp')dnl

The problem right now is that I'm not getting any emails forwarded. This is the tail of maillog, after a couple of minutes of sending an email to yehiasalam@grantorino.io. As you can see I'm not getting any activity at all. [image]

Comment: It doesn't appear the server is receiving any messages.  Try using telnet to diagnose. SMTP is a conversational protocol easy to emulate using a terminal session.  For GMail, you likely want to setup an authenticated outgoing connection.

Comment: You MUST use an authenticated connection to Gmail. Otherwise your forwarding will be seen as forging emails from domains that support DMARC or the older SPF.  In turn this will destroy any reputation associated with your IP address, and Gmail is likely to refuse any further emails from you regardless of possible authenticity.

Answer (score 0):

The `.io` top level domain seems to tell me the entire `grantorino.io` domain does not exist in the public DNS:

```
$ dig grantorino.io SOA
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 17264
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
io.                     823     IN      SOA     a0.nic.io. noc.afilias-nst.info. 1497562067 10800 3600 2764800 900

$ dig grantorino.io MX
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 24001
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
io.                     292     IN      SOA     a0.nic.io. noc.afilias-nst.info. 1497562067 10800 3600 2764800 900
```

Also, a reverse DNS query indicates there is no PTR record either, and that would cause your system to fail one of the oldest anti-spam tests:

```
$ dig -x 162.242.170.86
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 58070
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
170.242.162.in-addr.arpa. 300   IN      SOA     ns.rackspace.com. hostmaster.rackspace.com. 1543432701 3600 300 1814400 300
```

No wonder your domain cannot receive email: when viewed from the outside, it does not even seem to *exist*!